# Install cardreader on ZBOX nano CI320 with Bay-Trail-T Architecture

Tags: drivers

I installed Xubuntu on a ZBOX nano CI320.

It works all fine so far apart from the SD card reader, that doesn't get initialised. The main problem seems to be the Bay-Trail architecture.

How can I install the cartreader correctly on linux?

I would also install another distribution, if it would make the card reader run.

The problem is visible in `dmesg`:

```
[    2.117973] systemd-udevd[114]: starting version 204
[    2.139266] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.139272] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.142905] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:00: dummy supplies not allowed
[    2.142911] mmc0: no vqmmc regulator found
[    2.142915] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:00: dummy supplies not allowed
[    2.142917] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[    2.144032] mmc0: SDHCI controller on ACPI [80860F14:00] using ADMA
[    2.146311] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:01: dummy supplies not allowed
[    2.146320] mmc1: no vqmmc regulator found
[    2.146324] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:01: dummy supplies not allowed
[    2.146326] mmc1: no vmmc regulator found
[    2.147499] mmc1: SDHCI controller on ACPI [80860F14:01] using ADMA
[    2.147509] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:01: failed to setup card detect wake up
[    2.165262] ahci 0000:00:13.0: version 3.0
[    2.165458] ahci 0000:00:13.0: irq 104 for MSI/MSI-X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the kernel to at least version 3.17.  The instruction is here:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-upgrade-kernel-3-17-ubuntu/

However, newer kernel versions are not officially supported and you could run into instability issues.

Comment: We tried already kernel 3.18 on Xubuntu which works kind of, but the cardreader still is **really slow**. Maybe it will work better on arch Linux, we will try that in a few days